# Por que me tira error 404 mi web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, error404, webapi

Estoy arrancando en el desarrollo de API con NET.

Necesito de sus ayudas. Tengo una API en net y me tira el el error 404 (NotFound) al realizar la consulta al endpoint update.

Probé haciendo un debug e ingresa correctamente a los if y va al return Forbid() pero igualmente en el swagger me responde con un NotFound. No se si es problema de ruta, pero aparentemente está todo bien.

El create me funciona correctamente.

```
namespace OngProject.Controllers {
[Route("comments")]
[ApiController]
public class CommentController : ControllerBase

{
    private readonly ICommentService _commentService;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly INewService _newService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CommentController(ICommentService commentService, 
        INewService newService, IUserService userService, 
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this._commentService = commentService;
        this._userService = userService;
        this._newService = newService;
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this._mapper = mapper;
    }

    //[Authorize(Roles = "standard")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CommentDTO comment)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var _new = await _newService.GetById(comment.news_id);
        if (_new == null)
            return NotFound("New not found");
        var user = await _userService.GetById(comment.user_id);
        if (user == null)
            return NotFound("User not found");
        var _comment = _mapper.Map<Comments>(comment);
        var created = await _commentService.CreateAsync(_comment);
        if (created)
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
        return Created("Created", new { Response = StatusCode(201) });
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("/comments/{id}")]
    //[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(CommentDTO))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)] //no tiene permiso
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, CommentDTO commentDTO)
    {
        var entity = await _commentService.GetById(id);
        var user = await _userService.GetById(commentDTO.user_id);
        if (user == null)
            return Forbid();        

        if (ModelState.IsValid && entity != null)
        {
            _commentService.UpdateComment(entity, commentDTO);
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
            return new OkObjectResult(commentDTO);
        }
        return NotFound();            
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que para usar la función Forbid(), debes tener bien configurado tu autorización en tu API. Prueba cambiando por: return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)

Comment: si, era eso. muchas gracias!